# Is there a way to filter noisy stack frames from Intellij's debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, callstack

I'm trying to debug some code using Intellij's debugger, and the call stack is filled with AOP and proxy-related stack frames.  It makes it really hard to locate relevant stack frames.  Is there a way to filter these besides filtering out *all* library stack frames?

Comment: Have you tried 'Skip synthetic methods' option? (See [Customize Threads View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/customize-threads-view.html) and [Debugger -> Stepping](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/stepping.html)) Is this what you look for?

Answer (score 8):

Sure!

Your *Frames* tab has a little funnel icon [image: funnel] that you can use to hide frames from known libraries. Check it out:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for hint. How can I filter the libraries by  group id? I need to filter out the org.jboss stuff but need to keep the libs frames from our company. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: @ArthurEirich Currently, it is not. Please see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205261

Answer (score 1):

It seems that is not possible. Here is the feature request for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191180 (you can vote if you have an account).