# how to hide specific frames in debugger window in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

I know that i can hide frames from libraries by clicking the button above, but I wanna view a few libraries of those in the debug window, how can I do that?

my intellij version: IU-171.4424.56

Comment: Request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Seems to be captured here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191180

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's currently impossible.

Please vote for this feature here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191180 (credits to @xdhmoore comment).